# XSLT - replace value in one node with the value from it's preceeding sibling

Tags: xml, search, xslt, xpath, replace

I'm trying to write an XSLT transformation which will replace the value in one node with the value of it's preceding sibling. Then return the entire document transformed :)

Find the occurrences of

```
<package:packageDownloadLocator>http://myunwantedurl</package:packageDownloadLocator>
```

and replace with the text value of it's proceeding sibling

```
<package:packagePreviewLocator>http://myurl.com</package:packagePreviewLocator>
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Note: The node to be found does not always exist in each record.

From this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<SRW:searchRetrieveResponse xmlns:SRW="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/" xmlns:DIAG="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/diagnostics" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:package="info:srw/extension/13/package-v1.0">
<SRW:records>
<SRW:record>
   <SRW:recordData>
    <dc:dc>
     <dc:title xml:lang="en">Opportunities for involvement for service users and carers at the Open University in Scotland</dc:title>
     <dc:description xml:lang="en">Booklet explaining the different ways service users or carers can assist</dc:description>
     <dc:publisher>Open University</dc:publisher>
     <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
     <dc:type>Narrative Text</dc:type>
     <dc:rights xml:lang="en">Copyright Open University, 2009</dc:rights>
     <dc:subject>health and health care, health care, nursing</dc:subject>
    </dc:dc>
   </SRW:recordData>
   <SRW:extraRecordData>
    <package:packagePreviewLocator>http://myurl.com</package:packagePreviewLocator>
    <package:packageDownloadLocator>http://myunwantedurl</package:packageDownloadLocator>
    <record:record xmlns:record="http://srw.o-r-g.org/schemas/rec/1.0/">
     <record:lastModified>2009-09-29</record:lastModified>
     <record:created>2009-09-29</record:created>
    </record:record>
   </SRW:extraRecordData>
  </SRW:record>
 </SRW:records>
</SRW:searchRetrieveResponse>
```

To this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SRW:searchRetrieveResponse xmlns:SRW="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/" xmlns:DIAG="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/diagnostics" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:package="info:srw/extension/13/package-v1.0">
<SRW:records>
<SRW:record>
   <SRW:recordData>
    <dc:dc>
     <dc:title xml:lang="en">Opportunities for involvement for service users and carers at the Open University in Scotland</dc:title>
     <dc:description xml:lang="en">Booklet explaining the different ways service users or carers can assist</dc:description>
     <dc:publisher>Open University</dc:publisher>
     <dc:format>application/pdf</dc:format>
     <dc:type>Narrative Text</dc:type>
     <dc:rights xml:lang="en">Copyright Open University, 2009</dc:rights>
     <dc:subject>health and health care, health care, nursing</dc:subject>
    </dc:dc>
   </SRW:recordData>
   <SRW:extraRecordData>
    <package:packagePreviewLocator>http://myurl.com</package:packagePreviewLocator>
    <package:packageDownloadLocator>http://myurl.com</package:packageDownloadLocator>
    <record:record xmlns:record="http://srw.o-r-g.org/schemas/rec/1.0/">
     <record:lastModified>2009-09-29</record:lastModified>
     <record:created>2009-09-29</record:created>
    </record:record>
   </SRW:extraRecordData>
  </SRW:record>
 </SRW:records>
</SRW:searchRetrieveResponse>
```

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution that employs one of the most fundamental XSLT design patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:package="info:srw/extension/13/package-v1.0" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="package:packageDownloadLocator/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document, produces the wanted result**.

***Do note***:

1. **The use of the identity rule** to copy every node as is.
2. **The overriding of the identity rule with a specific template** that matches only the desired text node.

Comment: Thanks VERY much Dimitre, you've given me a massive amount of help here & and insight into XSLT :)

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the "Identity Transformation" (Google it, there's a good page at Wikipedia).  All you need is an identity transform plus a template that matches the tag you want to change.  You'll also have to decide if you want *any* preceding sibling, or a specific preceding tag (and what to do if there's no preceding sibling).